# important topics for linux programming in C

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel

i have an interview in 10 days for a job. requirements are: (1)Strong Linux kernel or device driver design and programming.(2)Demonstrated skills in C/C++ programming under Linux, and system prototyping with good knowledge of Linux and Windows server technologies.
since i hv only 10 days,  hw can i learn somethings which would help me in the interview.

Comment: This question suggests it might not be the job for you.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned if you meet any of the requirements...

Comment: Crazy company, who will take you. Who think he can touch Sky?

Answer (score 1):

I think Mr McLaughlin is right, for a lot of reasons, first of all because you can't learn how to move (as a user and also as a programmer) in linux in just 10 days.

Anyway, you should read this one: http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk-toc.html

You also have to know how POSIX systems work and take a look at this: http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs.html

This two links are a bunch of stuff for 10 days (since you should read&try everything to get used to it) but I think you have to read them to get a little (very basic) understanding on how life goes on on a linux-powered machine.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In 10 days you probably won't have time to learn enough, so don't aim to get that precise job.

But if Linux is interesting for you, consider

- installing and using a Linux distribution on your computer
- reading the [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) book
- reading the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book
- becoming fluent in shell and command line Linux tools
- learning to build and install from its source code several free software
- actively contributing to some free software on Linux coded in C
- learning more about Linux system administration (at least being able to administrate with command line tools your computer).

This will take you months, not days!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Writing device drivers in Linux: A brief tutorial: http://fsmsh.com/1238

This:

HOWTO do Linux kernel development: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/HOWTO;hb=HEAD

And:

Linux Kernel Development (3rd Edition)

http://goo.gl/XS7hq (There is e-book version that is delivered immediately)